# Date field should populate todays date ONCE, when the picklist value status = 'new' for the FIRST time

Tags: process-builder, workflow, formula-field

When the picklist value changes to new for the first, I want my date field to be updated for today's date. And this update should only happen once.
What should I go for in this case?

1. Formula field
2. Workflow
3. Process builder

Is this the correct formula?
IF(
AND( ISPICKVAL(STATUS, 'new') ), ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(STATUS),"new") ),
TODAY(), ''
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both workflow and process builder can be used for this.  Since Workflows are a bit simpler to manage, I'd recommend that route.

If you use the setting "created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria", you won't need to check the prior value.  Just use the workflow criteria STATUS = "New" and YOURDATEFIELD = null.

Then set the formula value of the field update to TODAY()

The above will populate the field only once, and leave the original value on future edits.

Good luck!